# VIM indent setting is not working

Tags: vim

My Vim's indent setting sets a width of 4 and disables auto indent, as opposed to what I have set up in `.vimrc`. Therefore, I always have to `:so ~/.vimrc` manually to make it works.

I can see that my `.vimrc` is loaded at start up when running `strace -o vim_strace vim`. Here is my `.vimrc`

```
set autoread
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required


" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

set number
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=2 smarttab
if &term =~ "xterm\\|rxvt"
  " use an orange cursor in insert mode
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]12;orange\x7"
  " use a red cursor otherwise
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]12;red\x7"
  silent !echo -ne "\033]12;red\007"
  " reset cursor when vim exits
  autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\033]112\007"
  " use \003]12;gray\007 for gnome-terminal and rxvt up to version 9.21
endif
```

Comment: plugins are sourced *after* your vimrc. have a look at `:verbose set sw?` to have a look which one overrides your setting

Comment: You can also have settings [after](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372277/7976758) plugins.

Comment: @phd link referes to a question with the right answer, but please ignore the question. DO NOT change the source order of vim. here is another article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

are you getting any errors when your start vim?

What I would first try is: 

 `set tabstop=2 
 set softtabstop=0 
 set expandtab 
 set shiftwidth=2 
 set smarttab`

Comment: That would actually work, but to set them automatically and follow Vim's source order, the comments in the question pointed me to the right answer. Thanks anyway.